# How to migrate from using one foreign key to another in ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, database-migration

Using Postgres as the backing store, I have a table which (at least for the time being) has both an integer primary key and a uuid with a unique index.

It looks something like this in my `schema.rb` (simplified for example):

```
create_table "regions", force: cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "region_id" 
  t.uuid     "uuid",        default: "uuid_generate_v4()"
  t.string   "name"
end

add_index "regions", ["uuid"], name "index_regions_on_uuid", unique: true, using :btree
```

I then have a table which has a reference to the integer id, something like this:

```
create_table "sites", force:cascade do 
  t.integer  "site_id"
  t.integer  "region_id"
  t.string   "name"
end
```

What I want to do is to switch from `region_id` to `uuid` as the foreign key in the second table.  How should I god about writing this migration?

Comment: Do you want to change the name of the `sites` table's `region_id` to `uuid`? Or do you want to change the column that `region_id` references on `regions` for the association?

Comment: @eirikir It's the latter, I want to replace the `sites.region_id` with a uuid typed column that references the `regions.uuid` column, instead of the `regions.region_id` column.  It can be a new column with a new name or the same one, but altered, whichever makes for a more seamless migration and refactoring.

Comment: @derekv I updated my answer with association code – now it seems to me very explicit and I see no reason for you to dislike it :)

Comment: @EugZol We where looking at both your answer and eirikir's and managed to get something working locally, however the problem is tougher then it first seems because you bump into a catch22, where the migration refers to a relation defined in the model but also changes that relation, so it won't work when your teammate pulls the code... maybe this is what your alluding to your edited answer, so I'll give it a shot as soon as I can.

Comment: @derekv You are right, I fixed specifically this issue.

Comment: @derekv Hey man! Any progress with an issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a migration, and inhale some SQL magic into it:

```
def up
  # Create and fill in region_uuid column,
  # joining records via still existing region_id column
  add_column :sites, :region_uuid

  if Site.reflect_on_association(:region).foreign_key == 'region_id'
    # We won't use 'joins(:regions)' in case we will need
    # to re-run migration later, when we already changed association
    # code as suggested below. Specifying join manually instead.
    Site.joins("INNER JOIN regions ON site.region_id = regions.id").update_all("region_uuid = regions.uuid")
  end

  drop_column :sites, :region_id
end
```

Then you just need to fix your association:

```
class Site < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :region, primary_key: :uuid, foreign_key: :region_uuid
end

class Region < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sites, primary_key: :uuid, foreign_key: :region_uuid
end
```

Answer (score 2):

From your comment, its seems that you want to modify the *primary key* referenced by the association, not the foreign key. You actually don't need a migration to do this. Instead, just specify the primary key on the association definitions in each model:

```
Class Region << ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sites, primary_key: :uuid
end

Class Site << ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :region, primary_key: :uuid
end
```

The foreign key, since it follows rails convention of being named as the `belongs_to` relation with an appended `"_id"` (in this case, `region_id`), does not need to be specified here.

**ETA:** You will also need to ensure that the type of `sites.region_id` matches the type of `regions.uuid`, which I assume is `uuid`. I'm also going to assume that this field was previously indexed (under ActiveRecord convention) and that you still want it indexed. You can change all this in a migration like so:

```
def up
  remove_index :sites, :region_id
  change_column :sites, :region_id, :uuid
  add_index :sites, :region_id
end

def down
  remove_index :sites, :region_id
  change_column :sites, :region_id, :integer
  add_index :sites, :region_id
end
```

Comment: The database schema currently has `sites.region_id` as type `integer`... So I think some migration must be necessary, right?